# How to apply rule to child element only after It is created (CSS)?

Tags: html, css, button

Okay, so my problem is that the button is working as It should except, the whole document is the parent until I hover so everything will become grey. How can I solve this?

Here's a link to see the problem with the grey box that's flashing.
https://jsfiddle.net/w0rec4gs/

```css
.btn-2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.btn-2:hover {
  transform: translate(-12px, -12px);
}

.btn-2:hover:after {
  transform: translate(6px, 6px);
}

.btn-2:hover:before {
  transform: translate(12px, 12px);
}

.btn-2::after,.btn-2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .3;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-2">Button 2</button>
```

Comment: I haven't understood the question, could you please clarify a bit? also a https://jsfiddle.net/ or something like that demonstrating the issue would be great :)

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you want to ask my friend. May be add Some HTML as well,.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question to meet the SO guidelines. Add your HTML to your CSS as a minimal reproducable code snippet (Ctrl + M). So that we can reproduce and see the issue here.

Comment: So I've edited the question with a JSFiddle link. The HTML isn't really an issue because It is simply an empty page with a button.

Comment: So, what is basically the Issue. We hover then what? What is the problem mate?

Comment: The problem is that the whole site becomes grey and It starts blinking if we are not hovered on the button.

Comment: @SirIQ78 have you notice that, you have done width:100%;and height:100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that doesn't happen just add position relative to the button. The absolutely positioned elements (your after and before) are positioning themselves in relation to your element instead of their direct parent which is the body

```
.btn-2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
```